# how to disable a text if number of divs is less than 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there is a list of elements and i expand each element on click the more button and collapse each element when click on the less button.but my problem is : i would like to hidden more button if div with classname "uner-sch" is only 2. furtheremore show that button.
here is my codes :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidi{
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
        3
        </div>

          <div class="uner-sch">
        5
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
<script>
var curHeight = $('.hidi').height();
$(".more").click(function(){
    var container = $(this).parent('.container');
    var el = container.find('.hidi');
    var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    if(el.hasClass('open')){
        el.removeClass('open');
        el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... less -');
    }
    else{
        el.addClass('open');
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... more +');
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('#textbox').prop('disabled', $('myDivs').length < 2));`

Comment: @Tushar i want to disable "more.."  button if the legnth of div is less than 2

Comment: Just change the selectors.

Comment: @Tushar i changed the selector but not worked. i want to disable more button if the divs in each container with classname:hidi is less than 2.

Comment: For _each_, you need to iterate over all the containers and if any of them is having less than 2 `.hidi` elements, disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust height of "hidi" div by using addClass or removeClass inside the loop of custom style element.

```js
var curHeight = $('.hidi').height();
$(".more").click(function(){
    var container = $(this).parent('.container');
    var el = container.find('.hidi');
    var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    if(el.hasClass('open')){
        el.removeClass('open');
        el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... less -');
    }
    else{
        el.addClass('open');
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... more +');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').each(function(){
           if($(this).find('.uner-sch').length > 2){
               $(this).find('.more').show();
           } else{
               $(this).find('.more').hide();
           }
        });
    });
```

```css
.hidi{
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
        3
        </div>

          <div class="uner-sch">
        5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         2
        </div>
        <div class="uner-sch">
         3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="hidi">
        <div class="uner-sch">
        1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more"> ... More +</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.more').prop('disabled', $('div.hidi').length < 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var curHeight = $('.hidi').height();
    $(".more").click(function () {
        //count number of divs with class `uner-sch`
        var numOfDivs = $('.uner-sch').length;

        if (numOfDivs < 2){
            $('.more').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        var container = $(this).parent('.container');
        var el = container.find('.hidi');
        var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        if(el.hasClass('open')){
            el.removeClass('open');
            el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... less -');
        }
        else{
            el.addClass('open');
            el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000), $(this).text('... more +');
        }
    });

});
```

Try this code and let me know it is working for you or not.

I hope this will help. Thanks.

Comment: it is not working for me. for example: in your code i want to remove more button in second part.